# notation for factoraling a factorial? (since one cannot do n!!)

Tags: factorial

I was thinking about how to get a number to be larger than graham's number very easily... came up with "factoraling" a factorial. However the notation n!! means something completely different. And I don't even think things like n!!! or n!!!! exist... or do they?

Anyway... how would one express or talk about the following?

3!! = 6! = 720

3!!! = 6!! = 720! = broken calculator...

3!!!! = 6!!! = 720!! = broken calculator! = stupidly huge number......

3!!!!...!'s = bazillion times bigger than graham's number

How do I express "n" number of "!'s" after the 3?

Comment: (n!)!? $\phantom{}$

Comment: I think you underestimate the size of Graham's number.

Comment: The number of !'s you need in order for 3!!!!...! to be bigger than Graham's number is more than you can possibly type in your lifetime.  Even if you chose a notation to denote $n$ iterated factorials, the number of digits you need to describe $n$ would still be greater than you could type in your lifetime.

Comment: Can't be far off, broke my calculator using only 3 "!'s" whole lot more room for more !'s by doing a function where the number of "!'s" after 3 is a function of 3 with a ton of "!'s" after it. Rinse and repeat till sufficient massive beyond comprehension. Heck, if I start with 9 and the number is so massive after only 2-3 "!'s".

Comment: That's rather like saying that, because we can't do a manned flight to Mars, the distance from Earth to Alpha Centuari can't be that much more. Both are out of reach of our technology, so to speak, but one much much more so than the other! (And this comparison is probably too _generous_---Graham's number is just that big!)

Comment: @CharlesMiller This procedure may produce numbers beyond your *imagination*, but not beyond comprehension, and still smaller than Graham's number.

Comment: @ErickWong surely repetitively "factoralizing" a number has a growth greater than a simple power tower (recall that factorials grow faster than exponential in a 1:1 ratio).

Comment: @CharlesMiller $n! < 2^{2^n}$.  Factorial adds nothing new to the game, nothing at all.

Comment: but (n!)! > 2^2^n or no?

Comment: Very easy way to get a number larger than Graham's number: take the factorial of Graham's number. :P

Comment: @CharlesMiller (n!)! < 2^2^2^2^n.  Any factorial chain is dominated by a power tower of merely double the length.  Doubling the length adds nothing new to the game, nothing at all.

Comment: i see so the factorials stacking up would basically "halve" the height of the power tower

Comment: @CharlesMiller Yup, you got it :).

Comment: To give some specifics for the next few iterates of the factorial (i.e. the calculator-breaking values), taking $n!\sim (n/e)^n \sqrt{2\pi n}$ (Stirling's formula) gives $((3!)!)!=720!\sim 10^{1746}\sim 10^{10^3},$ and $(720!)!\sim 10^{10^{1750}}\sim 10^{10^{10^3}}$. Those look big, but compared to the growth of other hyperoperations this really isn't that fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To take the factorial of a factorial, you should parenthesise, as suggested by arctic tern: $(n!)!$ would be appropriate.

I don't know of any convenient notation for a $k$-times iterated factorial, but that is probably because when dealing with such large numbers, one does not need to be so precise as to differentiate between factorials and exponentials.  In the latter case, Knuth's compact up-arrow notation allows for the expression of very large numbers.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) for details, but essentially:

$a \uparrow b = a^b$ is $a$ multiplied by itself $b$ times.

$a \uparrow \uparrow b = \left. a^{a^{...^a} } \right\} b \text{ times} $ is a tower of $b$ copies of $a$; that is, $a$ up-arrowed by itself $b$ times.

$a \uparrow \uparrow \uparrow b = \underbrace{a \uparrow \uparrow (a \uparrow \uparrow (a ... \uparrow \uparrow a) )}_{b \text{ times}} $, and in general

$a \uparrow^m b = \underbrace{a \uparrow^{m-1} ( a \uparrow^{m-1} (a ... \uparrow^{m-1} a) )}_{b \text{ times}}$.

It boggles the mind (well, my mind) to try to grasp how quickly these numbers grow.